# VBScript Reg. Expression not working as tested elsewhere

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I have taken a common password validation Reg. Expression pattern from RegExr and modified it slightly for character range. Testing this pattern fine on the same site at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

My problem is that when I then use this within my CLASSIC ASP scripting on the same test string, it seems to be returning me false and for the life of me cannot figure out why this is.

As far as I know the VBScript Regex system uses the same flavour of Reg Expressions as Javascript or am I wrong in that thought and need to modify the pattern for vbscript?

Pattern and code test within Classic ASP

```
Set objRegExpr = New regexp
    objRegExpr.IgnoreCase = false
    objRegExpr.Multiline = false
    objRegExpr.Global = false

    objRegExpr.Pattern = "^(?=[\x21-\x7E]*[0-9])(?=[\x21-\x7E]*[A-Z])(?=[\x21-\x7E]*[a-z])(?=[\x21-\x7E]*[\x21-\x2F|\x3A-\x40|\x5B-\x60|\x7B-\x7E])[\x21-\x7E]{8,12}$"

    str = "lA@d$awdw456"
    reMtch = objRegExpr.Test(str)
    Response.Write str & " = " & reMtch
```

Comment: For readability it would be better to replace all the `(?=[\x21-\x7E]*` with `(?=.*` as you are limiting the characters with `[\x21-\x7E]{8,12}` anyway. And the `|` in the penultimate character class are unnecessary/misplaced.

Comment: RegExr is not recommended for your case, since you are most likely using .NET regex. regexhero is better suited, since it is a regex tester for .NET.

Comment: I would guess that the regex engine doesn't support look-aheads, so instead you could test for the presence of each character type using separate regex. Or perhaps it's the hex codes it doesn't like - try it without.

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for the replies. MikeM, OK I will test seperately for each as suggested. nhahtdh, its not .NET, its classic ASP for an old Win2000 server.

Comment: So the expected value is `True`? I just ran this in a .vbs file on Win7 and I got True. According to [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y7bh5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), Win2K comes with VBScript 5.1 and RegExp was introduced in 5.0. According to [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html), many regexp features (possibly including lookahead) were introduced in version 5.5.

Comment: @MikeM VBScript supports look-aheads but no look-behinds. Edit: on another thought, I just read the comment of Cheran Shunmugavel and I think he is right and if so, so are you.